# How to get the list elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the list elements using jquery. I tried but not getting the result.

The code is

```html
<div class="paragraph"><ol>
    
    <li>I want a <a href="https://www.111.com" target="_blank">Chocolate</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> Cookie</span></li>
    <li>I want a <a href="https://www.222.com" target="_blank">Strawberry</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> Icecream</span></li>
    
    
    <li>I want a good<ol><li>Chicken <a href="https://www.333.com" target="_blank">Sandwich</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> and large fries</span></li>
    
    <li>Veg <a href="https://www.444.com" target="_blank">Burger</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> with cheese</span></li>

    </ol></li></ol></div>
```

I want to get the entire list text using its href element. If I give https://www.111.com, the jquery should return "I want a Chocolate Cookie"

If I give https://www.444.com, the jquery should return not only "Veg Burger with cheese", but also including its parent "I want a good Veg Burger with cheese"

It should automatically check for a parent list is present. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_I tried but not getting the result_" please post all the codes that you have tried.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I strongly recommend to NOT look for hrefs. There is a difference between your href, your .prop("href") your .attr("href") etc - Use data-attr instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      
  $("#btn").click(function() {
  let url = $("#url").val();
    $("#result").text(`Looking for [${url}]`);
    
    let link = $(`a[href="${url}"]`);
    if (link.length>0) {
      let li = link.parents("li").last();

      $("#result").text(`${li.text()}`);
    } else {
      $("#result").text(`no item found for ${url}`);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paragraph">
  <ol>

    <li>I want a <a href="https://www.111.com" target="_blank">Chocolate</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> Cookie</span></li>
    <li>I want a <a href="https://www.222.com" target="_blank">Strawberry</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> Icecream</span></li>


    <li>I want a good
      <ol>
        <li>Chicken <a href="https://www.333.com" target="_blank">Sandwich</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> and large fries</span></li>

        <li>Veg <a href="https://www.444.com" target="_blank">Burger</a><span style="color:rgb(80, 141, 36)"> with cheese</span></li>

      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Enter a url" value="https://www.111.com">
<button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: no item found for `https://www.444.com/`

Comment: @mplungjan you have to type the entire complete url with `https://www`

Comment: I right clicked and copied the url  - stack comments remove the https

Comment: @mplungjan I don't know what you are trying to do. I added a screenshot of the code working as it should. Check my edited answer

Comment: Copying and pasting adds a trailing slash

Comment: Try this for fun    `console.log(url,new URL(url),link.prop("href"),link.attr("href"))`